# Does heartbleed effect effect electronic voting

Tags: heartbleed, electronic-voting

Is electronic voting software compromised by the heartbleed issue?

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down, does it use **OpenSSL** Y/N?

- Y = Possible vulnerable if it uses version '1.0.1 through 1.0.1f (inclusive)
- N = It is not vulnerable

Source: http://heartbleed.com/

Answer (score 1):

Certainly could be. You'd need to do an analysis of a specific system to confirm.